# Using scrapy to parse items and improve code speed/overall performance

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, scrapy, pipeline

I am working on a project to **webscrape** large volumes of data daily and input them into a database. I have been attempting to do it as methodically as possible. I was able to create a parse function that was able to extract data from multiple pages. However, when I added a parse item function I kept failing. I have gone over the Scrapy documentation and tried to follow it as best as possible but to no avail.

I have been stuck for a few days and wanted to ask the Stack Overflow community for assistance. I apologize if my question is really long. I have been so confused that I wanted to see if I could get a thorough explanation/guidance, rather than keep posting question after question for each and every problem I encountered. I just want to make my project as efficient and well-done as possible. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you^^

**Full Code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

dt_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
file_name = dt_today+' HPI Data'

    # Create Spider class
    class UneguiApartments(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'unegui_apts'
        allowed_domains = ['www.unegui.mn']
        custom_settings = {'FEEDS': {f'{file_name}.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},
                       'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"}
        start_urls = [
        'https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        cards = response.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"announcement-container")]')
        for card in cards:
            name = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='name']/@content").extract_first()
            price = card.xpath(".//*[@itemprop='price']/@content").extract_first()
            date_block = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/text())").extract_first().split(',')
            date = date_block[0].strip()
            city = date_block[1].strip()
            link = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='url']/@href").extract_first()

            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_item)
            yield {'name': name,
                   'price': price,
                   'date': date,
                   'city': city,
                   'link': 'https://www.unegui.mn' + link
                   }

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # extract things from the listinsg item page
        spanlist = response.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, )]//text()').extract()
        alist = response.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='url']/@href").extract()

        list_item1 = spanlist[0].strip()
        list_item2 = spanlist[1].strip()
        list_item3 = alist[0].strip()
        list_item4 = alist[1].strip()

        yield {'item1': list_item1,
                'item2': list_item2,
                'item3': list_item3,
                'item4':list_item4
        }

        next_url = response.xpath(
            "//a[contains(@class,'red')]/parent::li/following-sibling::li/a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_url:
            # go to next page until no more pages
            yield response.follow(next_url, callback=self.parse)

    # main driver
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        process = CrawlerProcess()
        process.crawl(UneguiApartments)
        process.start()
```

**Current Results:**
[image: results]

**Run logs:** https://pastebin.com/LFiwQWZ6

**Expected Results:**
These are the scraped results before I added an item parse function. I want to add my item parse and scrape an additional 13 values inside an href list and a spanlist (reference: Item Picture Snippet & HTML snippet) and add it to the results in my expected results.

[image: results2]

**Item Picture Snippet:**

[image: Items]

**Item HTML Snippet:**
[image: HTML]

**Sidenote if anyone has the time or interest to guide me further. In the future I am planning to add to my code so I can:**

1. Use something like selenium to be able to scrape dynamic pages (e.g. be able to click on a button that reveals text/data, and then be able to scrape that).
2. Clean, transform, and normalize the scraped data.
3. Add to a DBeaver database.
4. Check and remove duplicates so there is only 1 unique apartment listing in the database.
5. Run a scheduled web scraper once a day automatically.

Hopefully, I want to scrape all categories of data from https://www.unegui.mn using **scraping** and make a spider for each category. The website has ~94,000 listings. Once completed, ideally I want to add a few more different websites to get additional advertisement listings.

Currently, I am scraping and outputting as a CSV file. Ideally, I want to be able to not only output as a CSV file on choice but to upload my data directly to a DBeaver database. I understand this is a large undertaking, but I really want to make a complex and diverse scrapy code that can be used to collect a large volume of data daily. Is this too ambitious? Once again, thank you for any and all input, and I apologize for the long post.

**Questions:**

1. Is it better to use one spider for each category from one website,
   or one spider per website?
2. Should I put all my web listings scraping code into one project folder or split them up?
3. Is there a naming convention I should follow?
4. Will using ItemLoader() and Input and Output make my code more efficient and faster? If not, taking into consideration my future additions, what path/method should I implement?
5. Are there any other methods or conventions I should follow to make my code as efficient and well-structured as possible?

Comment: How are you running your scrapy spider, through `scrapy crawl` command? Could you attach run logs. If you're on unix terminal you can do that with: `scrapy crawl unegui_apts 2>&1 | tee scrape.log`

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I updated my question and added a pastebin URL with the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at your logs there seems to be an error:

```
    raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /adv/5040771_belmonte/
```

I suspect this line is faulty as it might yield a request to a relative url where's Scrapy's Request objects always expect the url to be absolute:

```py
        cards = response.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"announcement-container")]')
        for card in cards:
            name = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='name']/@content").extract_first()
            price = card.xpath(".//*[@itemprop='price']/@content").extract_first()
            date_block = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/text())").extract_first().split(',')
            date = date_block[0].strip()
            city = date_block[1].strip()
            link = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='url']/@href").extract_first()

            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_item)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            yield {'name': name,
                   'price': price,
                   'date': date,
                   'city': city,
                   'link': 'https://www.unegui.mn' + link
                   }
```

The `link` variable here can be a relative link (like the one mentioned in your lgos `/adv/5040771_belmonte`.

To fix this either urljoin expliclitly:

```
yield Request(response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_item)
```

or use `response.follow` shortcut:

```
yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_item)
```

Further you should use item carry-over between your callbacks:

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        cards = response.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"announcement-container")]')
        for card in cards:
            # ...
            item = {'name': name,
                   'price': price,
                   'date': date,
                   'city': city,
                   'link': 'https://www.unegui.mn' + link
                   }
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_item, meta={"item": item})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # retrieve previously scraped item
        item = response.meta['item']
        # ... parse additional details

        item.update({'item1': list_item1,
                'item2': list_item2,
                'item3': list_item3,
                'item4':list_item4
        })
        yield item
        # ... next url
```

Comment: Thank you. When I use self.follow my yield on items don't return. So I get the same results I got before. I need to add the item results into my previous scraped data.

Comment: @Sod I'm not sure what you mean by that but I did a short review of your code and see my edit for a proposed solution. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much! I tweaked some stuff and got it to work. By chance do you happen to know how to ouput Cyrillic characters to a CSV file? When I view the file through PyCharm I can see all the text, but when I open the CSV file itself I get a bunch of ??? placeholders for Cyrillic text. I remember trying to output with utf-8 and it didn't affect it.

Comment: open csv file where? Maybe your program that reads the CSV (e.g. excel) doesn't understand utf encoding? Scrapy by default exports `utf-8` encoded data.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be caused by Excel. I've been trying to save using unicodecsv as csv package but no progress yet.